# Unassign keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Space in MS Teams during screen sharing

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to make Microsoft Teams not hijack the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on the computer during a screen sharing presentation?

This is the shortcut in Visual Studio to show all method parameters and I use it a lot when writing code and exploring unknown APIs. I had this a few times now that I was in a pair programming session and sharing my screen in Teams. Whenever I press this shortcut, it doesn't work in Visual Studio and instead shows an overlay panel at the top of the screen with useless content. Not sure what that's even good for. But it comes from Teams. As soon as the screen sharing ends, the shortcut works again in Visual Studio.

Comment: There is a [registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72981376/microsoft-teams-how-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts) you can create that will disable Microsoft Team keyboard shortcuts.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Tried it now, doesn't help.

Comment: How about using PowerToys to remap the shortcut? The registry key would require the user to logout and log back into their profile for it to take effect.

Comment: Can your provide details on that? I have PowerToys installed but don't know what to do with it in this case.

Comment: The answer on Stack Overflow that suggested PowerToys, included instructions, on how to do exactly that.  Did you read those instructions?

Comment: That doesn't apply. I don't want to change Ctrl+Shift+Space. There are two applications processing it, Teams overriding VS. I need Teams to stop doing that. Other keys (pressed or generated) won't help here.